# MVC - button action in view or controller?

Tags: iphone, ios, model-view-controller, uiviewcontroller

Using MVC. I have a button. Button drawing is in view. The button action should be in controller, right? How do I add action to the button? From view, no reference should be kept of controller (for MVC), then how to set action. 
Should the button be made public and accessed by controller?

Or, button should be drawn in controller. (not good)

Or, use a delegate (but then every view-controller pair in MVC will have to have a delegate)

Comment: Create a method to create button and there pass the reference for target of the action or create delegate.

Comment: If the action of the button is going to manipulate the view itself, have the functionality within the view, otherwise put it in a controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it. Has to set addTarget:nil. The action will be passed to next responder in chain. In this case view controller.

Answer (score 0):

**button should be accessible by the controller so that it can set an action.**

For example you could do it a little like it works with UITableCells :) --> you could have a property button on your view

BUT
this is a matter for debate and also depends on personal taste

Answer (score 0):

Create an IBAction in the header of your controller:

```
-(IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender;
```

Now in Interface Builder wire up your button to this action (use CTRL drag from button to files owner).

Next in the implementation of your controller you can write the code that executes when the button is pressed in `-(void)buttonPressed:(id)sender`

Comment: Any way if I am not using IB?

Comment: Yes, create a UIButton manually, then use addTarget to your button to link the button to your code

Comment: but then, I have to do addTarget:myController, and I don't, shouldn't have reference to myController

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can make the button is a property of your view. or you can make a public method of your view like `-(void)setupButtonSelector:(SEL)selector`; the selector is your buttons selector.

Answer (score 0):

Set a Target Selector on button which you are using in view. And Define a method with selector method name.

Ex:

```
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(YourMethodName) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]; // Declare this where you are adding button in view.

-(void)YourMethodName // Use this where you need to perform that button action.
{
   // Do what you need.
}
```

And if you are adding the view which contains that button at runtime.Try another trick.
Set a Tag Value for that button while adding button.And in Your controller access that button via its Tag value and add target on button.

Ex;

```
UIButton *btn = (UIButton*)[self.view viewWithTag:10];
    [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(methodName) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```